# YouTrack REST API - set default value on field

Tags: youtrack, youtrack-api

Using YouTrack API, is it possible to set the default value on a project's field?

For example, as part of a new-project automation routine I need to set the default value of the "Type" field from "Bug" to "Task".

Answer (score 1):

The option is available via UI. You may set default value under Administration> Projects> your project> click on "Default value" in front of "Type" field and select the target one (e.g. "Task").
Will this work for you?

Comment: I am automating the creation of a new project, and I want to automate what you just described **via the API**.  But it seems it is not possible at this time.

Comment: Correct, there is no such a method for now. Currently, it's possible to set default value via UI only. I've created a task https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-28915 , please, vote and watch for updates.